# how to get data-* attribute with asp.net ()

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have:

```
<input name="input4" type="text" id="input4" disabled="disabled" class="jsx-3771882255" data-id="0">
```

I want get data of data-id by C#;

```
string s=input4.Attributes["data-id"].ToString(); //(can'tuse this!)
```

Comment: You don't, data attributes are a client-side attribute, asp.net is serverside. You can set something to render client-side like a data attribute but you can only read what is sent back to the server via form element values or query string parameters (there are a couple of other exceptions but I'm simplifying)

Answer (score 2):

You have the disabled attribute set on your text box, this will not get submitted to the server, use the readonly attribute instead of the disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

@vuong quang - Can you check my code and implement it's working for me and also I shared my code with a screenshot.

**HTML Code**

Add runat="server"

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="0" data-id="101" runat="server" id="txtvalue" />
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGGtt.png)

**Code behind**

```
string id = txtvalue.Attributes["data-id"].ToString();
```

**Check below screenshots**

[CS Page Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1beuC.png)